# Color of links in JS-powered menu doesn't stay after click

Tags: css

I have a JS rollover switch, but when I click down on the link, the orange color doesn't stay, it reverts back to grey. What am I missing? Here is my code (orange is `color: #f7931d`):

CSS:

```css
#content-slider {
    padding-top:5px;
    height: 240px;
    width: 359px;
    padding-left: 52px;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #BBBDC0;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content-slider-inside {
    list-style: none;
    height: 240px;
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

    #content-slider-inside li {
        height: 340px;
        width: 359px;
        font-family: 'Century Gothic';
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #BBBDC0;
        display:inline-block;
        padding-bottom:25px;
    }

#navigation {
    font-family: 'Century Gothic';
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #BBBDC0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 940px;
    height: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation li {
    color:#bbbdc0;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

#navigation li a, #navigation li a:link, #navigation li a:visited {
    color:#bbbdc0;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;

}

#navigation li a.selected, #navigation li a.selected:link, #navigation li a.selected:visited, #navigation li a.selected:active {
    color:#f7931d;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation li a:hover, #navigation li a:focus, #navigation li a:active, #navigation li a:focus:active {
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#f7931d;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#overview">overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#features">features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#resumemanagement">resume management</a></li>
    <li><a href="#financials">financials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tracking">expense tracking</a></li>
    <li><a href="#search">search</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then the rest is basically just tags and anchors for when you click on the link.

```html
<div id="content-slider">
    <ul id="content-slider-inside">
        <li id="overview">
            text            
        </li>
        <li id="features">
            text
        </li>
        <li id="resumemanagement">
            text                
        </li>
        <li id="financials">
            text
        </li>
        <li id="tracking">
            text            
        </li>
        <li id="search">
            text            
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have some logic to apply the `selected` class to the active `a` tag after you click?

Comment: The `:active` pseudo-class only applies while there is a user-action, such as mouse-down. Once the user releases the button the `:active` no longer applies. And please could you strip your CSS down to the relevant portions, I don't think it's *all* relevant to this problem.

Comment: Add that styling to `a:visited` too.

Comment: I updated the above code. The jQuery doesn't help since it all is being done with "id" I did switch out addClass with addID and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking how to keep the menu item highlighted if its the current page. I discovered this handy little jQuery snippet on Stack Overflow a while ago, so I apologize that it is not attributed correctly. If someone recognizes this, please let me know and I will update with credits!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        $('[href$="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass("nav-active"); //replace nav-active class with your preferred highlighting class-- in this case the orange color.
    });
</script>
```

Basically it reads the browser URL, and if the end of the URL matches a menu item, it will keep it highlighted.